# No parameters supported exception while unwrapping key

Tags: android, security, android-keystore

I have this issue with android > 8
I'm using key wrapper for wrapping key with rsa algorithm.
Here is part of class

```
public byte[] wrap(SecretKey key) throws GeneralSecurityException {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.N_MR1) {
        OAEPParameterSpec sp = new OAEPParameterSpec("SHA-256",
                "MGF1", new MGF1ParameterSpec("SHA-1"),
                PSource.PSpecified.DEFAULT);
        cipher.init(Cipher.WRAP_MODE, pair.getPublic(), sp);
    } else {
        cipher.init(Cipher.WRAP_MODE, pair.getPublic());
    }
    return cipher.wrap(key);
}

public SecretKey unwrap(byte[] blob) throws GeneralSecurityException {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.N_MR1) {
        OAEPParameterSpec sp = new OAEPParameterSpec("SHA-256",
                "MGF1", new MGF1ParameterSpec("SHA-1"),
                PSource.PSpecified.DEFAULT);
        cipher.init(Cipher.UNWRAP_MODE, pair.getPrivate(), sp);
    } else {
        cipher.init(Cipher.UNWRAP_MODE, pair.getPrivate());
    }
    return (SecretKey) cipher.unwrap(blob, "AES", Cipher.SECRET_KEY);
}
```

I generate pair and store in android key store.

The problem is when i try to unwrap key i can get this exception

```
Unexpected parameters: javax.crypto.spec.OAEPParameterSpec@27572f4. No parameters supported
                                                                 java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: Unexpected parameters: javax.crypto.spec.OAEPParameterSpec@27572f4. No parameters supported
                                                                     at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreRSACipherSpi$PKCS1Padding.initAlgorithmSpecificParameters(AndroidKeyStoreRSACipherSpi.java:127)
                                                                     at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.engineInit(AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.java:147)
                                                                     at javax.crypto.Cipher.tryTransformWithProvider(Cipher.java:2659)
                                                                     at javax.crypto.Cipher.tryCombinations(Cipher.java:2570)
                                                                     at javax.crypto.Cipher$SpiAndProviderUpdater.updateAndGetSpiAndProvider(Cipher.java:2475)
                                                                     at javax.crypto.Cipher.chooseProvider(Cipher.java:566)
                                                                     at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:973)
                                                                     at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:908)
```

This exception is really rare. It can fire once a week or a month. So main thing is that the key was wrapped once and successfully unwrapped. Everything works fine until one magic moment when i am not able to unwrap key with the exception.

Has anybody encountered the same thing or have any clues?